# array list saved in pref, load each item only once

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-intent, video

I need to store a list of URLs, in pref.

```
[www.url1.com, www.url2.com, www.url3.com, www.url4.com, ]
```

I want to know how can I call the list array, and load each item only once. I.e. if item 1 been loaded, then mark as done. next time I call the list I get item 2.

There reason why I ask is:

I need to build a video player playList.

I will build a playList array and store all the URLs.

when the player activity start it will load url1, when this clip finish, it will load a splash activity for 5 seconds and then call the player activity again. (this time it has to load the url 2).

In the end, after all the urls have been played. I need to store analytic as successfully playlist.

The part I don't know how to handle is the PlayList. and how to load in order only one URL once.

Any feed back will be very helpful, I really appreciate your hep. thank.

Comment: your all url will be unique??

Comment: Use another arraylist,once url1 is played,update the second list array value at same index with true.Once all values of second list array are true,you can show Succesfully played.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over your list:

```
String[] urls = {"www.url1.com", "www.url2.com", "www.url3.com", "www.url4.com"}; 

        for(String url : urls){
            //do something with each url
            //each url will only be loaded once
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Mr T,

You can store the index of the url array in shared preference and after playing the video start your splash activity and after 5 secs , when you load the Player activity again, get the index saved in shared preference for playing the specific url.

Comment: Do you mean using ArrayList<HashMap> ?

Comment: no..what i m trying to say is, u just save the index of your arraylist of which url is currently playing in preferences.when u come back to the activity try to load the url which is next in index using preference...